# How to remove whitespace from end of string in Python?

Tags: python, whitespace, strip

I want to remove the whitespace at the end of 'Joe'

```
name = 'Joe'
print(name, ', you won!')
>>>Joe , you won!
```

I tried the rstrip method, but it didn't work

```
name='Joe'
name=name.rstrip()
print(name, ', you won!')
>>>Joe , you won!
```

My only solution was to concatenate the string

```
name='Joe'
name=name+','
print(name,'you won!')
>>>Joe, you won!
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to concatenate the strings to avoid unwanted spaces:

```
print(name + ', you won.')
```

Answer (score 11):

The [`print()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) **adds** whitespace between the arguments, there is nothing to strip there.

Use `sep=''` to stop the function from doing that:

```
print(name, ', you won!', sep='')
```

or you can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to create one string to pass to `print()`:

```
print('{}, you won!'.format(name))
```

Comment: You're so quick! LOL :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The white space is being added by `print` because you're passing it two parameters and this is how it works.

Try this:

```
print(name, ', you won!', sep='')
```

Another way would be doing some *string formatting* like:

```
print('%s, you won!' % (name))    # another way of formatting.
```